# what's having 0.0001 Bitcoin mean?

Tags: withdrawal

Having issues selling my bitcoins. Need assistance. My usd isnt showing correctly? It says I'm missing 11million but I never withdrew that much and when I do it totals out to like 20 dollars.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot says that the minimum withdrawal amount is 11 000 000 sats and your wallet's total funds appear to be 14 600 sats.